# High OS load and poor performance on specific cassandra nodes in a cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.1

I am using cassandra v2.1.13 in 10 node cluster with replication factor = 2 and LeveledCompactionStrategy. The nodes are c4.4x large types with 10g heap.

8 nodes in the cluster are performing fine but there is an issue with 2 particular nodes in the cluster. These nodes are constantly giving very poor read latency, and have a high dropped reads count. There is a continuous high OS load on these 2 nodes.

Below is the nodetool commands results from one of these nodes:

**status**

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                             Rack
UN  10.0.23.37   257.31 GB  256     19.0%             3e9ee62e-70a2-4b2e-ba10-290a62cd055b  1
UN  10.0.53.69   300.24 GB  256     20.5%             48988162-69d6-4698-9afa-799ef4be7bbc  2
UN  10.0.23.133  342.37 GB  256     21.1%             30431a62-0cf6-4c82-8af1-e9ba0025eba6  1
UN  10.0.53.7    348.52 GB  256     21.4%             5fcdeb25-e1e5-47f6-af7f-7bea825ab3c0  2
UN  10.0.53.88   292.59 GB  256     19.5%             c77904bc-10a8-49e0-b6fa-8fe8126e064c  2
UN  10.0.53.250  272.76 GB  256     20.6%             ecf417f2-2e96-4b9e-bb15-06eaf948cefa  2
UN  10.0.23.75   271.24 GB  256     20.8%             d8b0ab1b-65ab-46cd-b7e4-3fb3861ffb23  1
UN  10.0.23.253  302.9 GB   256     21.0%             4bb6408a-9aa0-42da-96f7-dbe0dad757bc  1
UN  10.0.23.238  326.35 GB  256     18.2%             55e33a97-e5ca-4c48-a530-a0ff6fa8edde  1
UN  10.0.53.222  247.4 GB   256     18.0%             c3a6e4c2-7ab6-4f3a-a444-8d6dff2beb43  2
```

**cfstats**

```
Keyspace: key_space_name
Read Count: 63815118
Read Latency: 88.71912845022085 ms.
Write Count: 40802728
Write Latency: 1.1299861338192878 ms.
Pending Flushes: 0
    Table: table1
    SSTable count: 1269
    SSTables in each level: [1, 10, 103/100, 1023/1000, 131, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    Space used (live): 274263401275
    Space used (total): 274263401275
    Space used by snapshots (total): 0
    Off heap memory used (total): 1776960519
    SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.3146938954387242
    Number of keys (estimate): 1472406972
    Memtable cell count: 3840240
    Memtable data size: 96356032
    Memtable off heap memory used: 169478569
    Memtable switch count: 149
    Local read count: 47459095
    Local read latency: 0.328 ms
    Local write count: 14501016
    Local write latency: 0.695 ms
    Pending flushes: 0
    Bloom filter false positives: 186
    Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
    Bloom filter space used: 1032396536
    Bloom filter off heap memory used: 1032386384
    Index summary off heap memory used: 495040742
    Compression metadata off heap memory used: 80054824
    Compacted partition minimum bytes: 216
    Compacted partition maximum bytes: 3973
    Compacted partition mean bytes: 465
    Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.1710125211397823
    Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
    Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
    Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0

    Table: table2
    SSTable count: 93
    SSTables in each level: [1, 10, 82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    Space used (live): 18134115541
    Space used (total): 18134115541
    Space used by snapshots (total): 0
    Off heap memory used (total): 639297085
    SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.2889927549599339
    Number of keys (estimate): 102804187
    Memtable cell count: 409595
    Memtable data size: 492365311
    Memtable off heap memory used: 529339207
    Memtable switch count: 433
    Local read count: 16357463
    Local read latency: 345.194 ms
    Local write count: 26302779
    Local write latency: 1.370 ms
    Pending flushes: 0
    Bloom filter false positives: 4
    Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
    Bloom filter space used: 73133360
    Bloom filter off heap memory used: 73132616
    Index summary off heap memory used: 30985070
    Compression metadata off heap memory used: 5840192
    Compacted partition minimum bytes: 125
    Compacted partition maximum bytes: 24601
    Compacted partition mean bytes: 474
    Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.9915609172937249
    Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
    Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
    Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
```

---

**tpstats**

```
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked All time blocked
MutationStage                     2         0       43617272         0                 0
ReadStage                        45       189       64039921         0                 0
RequestResponseStage              0         0       37790267         0                 0
ReadRepairStage                   0         0        3590974         0                 0
CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
HintedHandoff                     0         0             18         0                 0
GossipStage                       0         0         457469         0                 0
CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0
InternalResponseStage             0         0              0         0                 0
CommitLogArchiver                 0         0              0         0                 0
CompactionExecutor                1         1          60965         0                 0
ValidationExecutor                0         0            646         0                 0
MigrationStage                    0         0              0         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                  0         0           1938         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator            0         0             17         0                 0
Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0
MemtableFlushWriter               0         0           1997         0                 0
MemtablePostFlush                 0         0           4884         0                 0
MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0           1997         0                 0
Native-Transport-Requests        11         0       61321377         0                 0

Message type           Dropped
READ                     56788
RANGE_SLICE                  0
_TRACE                       0
MUTATION                   182
COUNTER_MUTATION             0
BINARY                       0
REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
PAGED_RANGE                  0
READ_REPAIR                  1
```

**netstats**

```
Mode: NORMAL
Not sending any streams.
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 2910144
Mismatch (Blocking): 0
Mismatch (Background): 229431
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed
Commands                        n/a         0       37851777
Responses                       n/a         0      101128958
```

**compactionstats**

```
pending tasks: 0
```

I verified that there is no continuous compaction running.
Upon taking the jstack on both the nodes, there were threads that were continuously calling the following stack in infinite loop - my guess is that the high os load is caused by these threads being stuck in loop and leading to slow reads.

```
SharedPool-Worker-7 - priority:5 - threadId:0x00002bb0356a0150 - nativeId:0x158ef - state:RUNNABLE
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.memory.HeapAllocator.allocate(HeapAllocator.java:34)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.memory.AbstractAllocator.clone(AbstractAllocator.java:34)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.NativeCell.localCopy(NativeCell.java:58)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController$2.apply(CollationController.java:223)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController$2.apply(CollationController.java:220)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:794)
at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter$2.getNext(QueryFilter.java:175)
at  org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter$2.hasNext(QueryFilter.java:156)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$Candidate.advance(MergeIterator.java:146)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.advance(MergeIterator.java:125)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.computeNext(MergeIterator.java:99)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.collectReducedColumns(SliceQueryFilter.java:264)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateColumns(QueryFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateOnDiskAtom(QueryFilter.java:82)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateOnDiskAtom(QueryFilter.java:69)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectAllData(CollationController.java:314)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:65)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2001)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1844)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.getRow(Keyspace.java:353)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.SliceFromReadCommand.getRow(SliceFromReadCommand.java:85)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadVerbHandler.doVerb(ReadVerbHandler.java:47)
at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService.java:164)
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

We tried increasing the instance size of the affected nodes, suspecting that they might be blocked on I/O ops but that did not help.

Can someone pls help me figuring out what is wrong with these 2 nodes in of the cluster.

Comment: `nodetool status <keyspace>` will tell you whether you have a hotspot in your data. `nodetool compactionstats` will tell you if your nodes are getting way behind on compactions. Please provide additional data to help diagnose.

Comment: @LHWizard have updated those 2. These stats were normal so I did not update them in the first place.

Comment: are you caught in "GC death spiral"? if you `grep GCInspector /var/log/cassandra/system.log` are your gc-times going way up? my GC is usually around 200-250ms.

Comment: The GC timings are still fine. I am using G1 gc and the times are around 200ms mark only. Just as I was experimenting with the cluster, turning on row cache seemed to help a lot, and read latency improved significantly, bringing down the OS load with it.